# rxkotlin groupby is not working

Tags: rx-kotlin2

could you please help me to group by the following json and return a hashMap in kotlin based on date with RxKotlin? is so easy with just kotlin but really stuck for Rxkotlin. thanks

val groupedTransactions =   accountTransactions.transactions
                    ?.groupBy { it.effectiveDate }

```
"transactions": [{
        "id": "44e5b2bc484331ea24afd85ecfb212c8",
        "effectiveDate": "20/07/2017",
        "description": "Kaching TFR from JOHN CITIZEN<br/>xmas donation",
        "amount": 12.00
    }, {
        "id": "1506aeeb8c3a699b1e3c87db03156428",
        "effectiveDate": "20/07/2017",
        "description": "Wdl ATM CBA ATM CIRCULAR QUAY STATION NSW 221092 AUS",
        "amount": -200.00,
        "atmId": "129382"
    }, {
        "id": "9a899bfd978511e9605774e1d5222b67",
        "description": "Savings",
        "effectiveDate": "19/07/2017",
        "amount": 10.00
    }, {
        "id": "1a6c48627cecaa2388b702fa33d751ff",
        "description": "PTAG COCA COLA AMATI",
        "effectiveDate": "12/07/2017",
        "amount": -2.20
    }, {
        "id": "7ecc19e1a0be36ba2c6f05d06b5d3058",
        "description": "Wdl ATM CBA ATM TOWN HALL SQUARE NSW 253432 AUS",
        "effectiveDate": "04/07/2017",
        "amount": -50.00,
        "atmId": "137483"
    }, {
        "id": "b71bf065b640217dad602f86ac047722",
        "description": "BPAY - Telstra mobile",
        "effectiveDate": "04/07/2017",
        "amount": -49.00
    },{
        "id": "ef087651eb482bae4624478696f4ad4f",
        "description": "Transfer from REBECCA SHAW<br/>Lorem ipsum",
        "effectiveDate": "03/07/2017",
        "amount": 150.00
    }, {
        "id": "8cd283d8b7bacc277f2bae5e26ce6d1e",
        "description": "Savings",
        "effectiveDate": "01/07/2017",
        "amount": 200.00
    }, {
        "id": "04117d2d74f5331f3ee4955da27cca7a",
        "effectiveDate": "28/06/2017",
        "description": "Transfer - Saturday drinks",
        "amount": -100.00
    }, {
        "id": "821ae63dbe0c573eff8b69d451fb21bc",
        "effectiveDate": "21/06/2017",
        "description": "Wdl ATM CBA ATM CIRCULAR QUAY STATION NSW 221092 AUS",
        "amount": -200.00,
        "atmId": "129382"
    }]
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why do you want to do this synchronous in-memory task with Rx?

Comment: Observable.fromIterable(accountTransactions.transactions)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .groupBy{ it -> Transaction::effectiveDate }
                        .subscribe({ group -> println("Key " + group.key)
                            group.subscribe {
                                x -> print("this is the key" + group.key.toString() + " : " + x.description)  }
                        })

Comment: this looks lik the rxkotlin issue. I've done it through coroutine kotlin like:              doAsync {
                    val groupedTransactions = accountTransactions.transactions
                            ?.groupBy { it.effectiveDate } ....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to post code in your question; don't be afraid to edit to make it more clear what you want to do, why you want to do it, what you've already tried, and why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks lik the rxkotlin issue. I've done it through coroutine kotlin like:

```
doAsync { val groupedTransactions = accountTransactions.transactions ?.groupBy { it.effectiveDate } ....
```