# I can't get map from groupby in rxkotlin

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin

could you please help me for this [rxkotlin groupby is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595813/rxkotlin-groupby-is-not-working)? working in rxjava but not kotlin. highly apreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rxkotlin groupby is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595813/rxkotlin-groupby-is-not-working)

Comment: Show your code what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doAsync { val groupedTransactions = accountTransactions.transactions ?.groupBy { it.effectiveDate } ....
```

Try this